# Deleting user from a form using php pdo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a table displaying a list of users from my database and I have added a delete button beside each row so that if I want to delete that row I click the delete button and the row should disappear from my database and the table displayed on the database.

When I click delete it redirects me to another page but doesn't delete anything in the database.  Please find attached my PHP for deleting users and the HTML table it is displaying from.

Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Ballymena Sports</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="home2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="home2_template.html">Ballymena Sports</a>
        </div>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="admin_login.php">Administrator</a></li>
            <li><a href="logout.php">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>

      </div>
    </nav>



    <!-- Main part of homepage -->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
          <h2>Users</h2>
          <p>This table shows all registered users of Ballymena Sports:</p>            

            <div class="table-responsive"> 
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                    include "config.php"; 

                    $query = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user ORDER BY userID asc");
                    $query->execute();


                    echo "<table id='user' class='table table-bordered'>
                          <tr>
                          <th>User ID</th>
                          <th>Username</th>
                          <th>Forename</th>
                          <th>Surname</th>
                          <th>Email</th>
                          <th>Address</th>
                          <th>Town</th>
                          <th>Postcode</th>
                          <th>Edit User</th> 
                          <th>Delete User</th>
                          </tr>";

                    while ($dbRow = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                        $userID = $dbRow['userID'];
                        $username = $dbRow['username'];
                        $forename = $dbRow['forename'];
                        $surname = $dbRow['surname'];
                        $email = $dbRow['email'];
                        $address1 = $dbRow['address1'];
                        $town = $dbRow['town'];
                        $postcode = $dbRow['postcode'];
                        // code to display information


               { echo "<tr>
                        <td>$userID</td>
                        <td>$username</td>
                        <td>$forename</td>
                        <td>$surname</td>
                        <td>$email</td>
                        <td>$address1</td>
                        <td>$town</td>
                        <td>$postcode</td>
                        <td><a href='edit_user.php'>Edit</a></td>
                        <td><a href='delete_user.php'>Delete</a></td>
                      </tr>";}
                }
                ?> 


            </tbody>
            </div>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php 


    if(!$_SESSION['admin_username']){
        header('location:admin_login.php'); 

        $name = $_SESSION['admin_username'];
    }

?> 

      <hr>



    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script> 
    <!-- Header and footer later to be used as include statements -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**DELETE.PHP**

```
<?php
/* 
 DELETE.PHP
 Deletes a specific entry from the 'players' table
*/

 // connect to the database
 include "config.php";

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['userID']))
 {
 // get id value
 $userID = $_GET['userID'];

 // delete the entry
    $query = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM user WHERE userID='$userID'");
    $query->execute();

 // redirect back to the view page
 echo'deleted';
 header("Location: view_user.php");
 }
 else
 // if id isn't set, or isn't valid, redirect back to view page
 {
     echo'no id'; 
 header("Location: admin_panel.php");
 }

?>
```

Comment: <td><a href='delete_user.php'>Delete</a></td> - <-- No ID for the $_GET in your php file, you need to add the userID to the link - Goes for your edit link too

Comment: Try to prevent SQL-injection in your code. Just  `$userID = intval($_GET['userID']);` would save a lot of nerves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass `$userId` to delete.php

```
<td><a href='delete_user.php?userId=".$userID."'>Delete</a></td>
```

Comment: I inserted the above code and it still isn't deleting any records from the table or the database?

Comment: I didn't enter the ?userID part properly, that's why it didn't work.  Thanks for the help very much appreciated!

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for that, quite new to stack exchange.  Answer accepted! :)